EntityFrameworkCore Pluralizer renamed Tax to Taxis
I'm using DbContext-Scaffold to reverse-engineer a database.
Name of the database table = BETax
I get the below generated DbContext
public virtual DbSet<BETaxis> BETaxes { get; set; }

I prefer to get the below instead
public virtual DbSet<BETax> BETaxes { get; set; }

How do I customize the pluralizer?
I'm using EFPT tool by Erik

You can configure uncountable words in the config file like this:
"UncountableWords": [
      "Taxi"
   ],

More info here

Thank Erik. I did not notice that config. EFPT rocks.
It works on other terms except for Tax. More info here https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/issues/1499
